Why is java.sql’s Timestamp.of() converting incorrectly from java.time’s LocalDateTime?
I ran into a bug where java.sql's
Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.MIN())

is converting incorrectly.
Given java.time's
 LocalDateTime.MIN() = -999999999-01-01T00:00:00

But when I try to convert it into an SQL friendly TimeStamp, why do I run into a differently parsed time which is incorrectly Skewed?
Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.MIN()) = +169087565-03-15 04:51:43.000000

I was expecting the oldest date possible, but this gives out a MAX.
PS:
I worked around it using
Timestamp.valueOf(//
        LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.ofYearDay(1800,1), LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)


As has been said, you should stick to your LocalDateTime, iy’s all you need. Avoid java.sql.Timestamp since it was a true hack on top of the already problematic Date class and has been outdated since JDBC 4.2. In any case your Timestamp was probably underflowing, you tried to give it a value outside the range it can hold.

Usage: there is no parsing going on in Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.MIN()). It’s a conversion. (Parsing is analysing a string of symbols.)

It’s nothing  we need to know since as I said, we should not use Timestamp. Of curiosity only new Timestamp(Long.MIN_VALUE).toLocalDateTime() yields +292278994-08-17T08:12:55.192. The minimum Timestamp value seems to be around 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0. Which probably agrees with the range supported by many SQL variants.

tl;dr
Never use Timestamp.



Purpose
Java
JDBC
SQL Standard




Represent a moment, a date with time-of-day within context of time zone or offset-from-UTC, a specific point on the timeline
Instant, OffsetDateTime, ZonedDateTime
java.time.OffsetDateTime
TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE


Represent merely a date with time-of-day (not a moment)
LocalDateTime
java.time.LocalDateTime
TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE



Avoid java.sql.Timestamp
You said:

SQL friendly TimeStamp

The java.sql.Timestamp class is one of the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310.
Use OffsetDateTime, not Timestamp
JDBC 4.2 and later requires every JDBC driver to support java.time. Specifically, use OffsetDateTime instead of Timestamp.
Java offers three classes to represent a moment: Instant, OffsetDateTime, and  ZonedDateTime. But only OffsetDateTime is mapped to a SQL type in JDBC because of the limitations of the SQL standard.

LocalDateTime

The LocalDateTime class cannot represent a moment as it lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC. The LocalDateTime class represents simply a date with time-of-day, nothing more.
Both the legacy type Timestamp and the modern type OffsetDateTime represent a moment, a point on the timeline. So you should not mix LocalDateTime with these.
Avoid minimums & maximums

.MIN

Avoid using the extremes of minimum/maximum. Database systems vary in their limits. All that I am aware of have a much smaller range than does java.time.
If you need some kind of signal value to indicate “old”, use a more contemporary value. For example, consider using java.time.Instant.EPOCH, the first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.
OffsetDateTime epoch = Instant.EPOCH.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;


I was expecting the oldest date possible, but this gives out a MAX.

Probably you are seeing the effects of a wraparound due to integer overflow.
The internal implementation of Timestamp uses a 32-bit integer count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00Z, negative before, positive after. The java.time classes use a much larger range by way of two counts, a 64-bit integer count of whole seconds from that same epoch reference plus a fractional second kept as a count of nanoseconds.
But there really is no point to exploring this issue. There is no reason to ever use java.sql.Timestamp.
Conversion
If handed a Timestamp, immediately convert using the new conversion methods added to the old classes. Specifically, java.time.Instant, then assign an offset to get a SQL-friendly OffsetDateTime object.
Instant instant = myTimestamp.toInstant() ;  // A moment as seen in UTC, always UTC. 
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;

If you need a Timestamp object to interoperate with old code not yet updated to java.time, convert.
java.sql.Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from( odt.toInstant() ) ;


The direct equivalent of JDBCs java.sql.Timestamp is java.time.LocalDateTime (which illustrates why the fact it was based on java.util.Date was a bad idea), as it is for SQL TIMESTAMP [WITHOUT TIME ZONE] columns, which do not have timezone information, and are always interpreted in the default JVM timezone for conversion to java.sql.Timestamp, unless one of the methods with a Calendar is used to retrieve them.

Also, you statement that "only OffsetDateTime is mapped to a SQL type in JDBC" is wrong. LocalDate is mapped to java.sql.Types.DATE (SQL standard DATE), LocalTime is mapped to TIME (SQL standard TIME [WITHOUT TIME ZONE]), LocalDateTime is mapped to TIMESTAMP (SQL standard TIMESTAMP [WITHOUT TIME ZONE], OffsetTime is mapped to TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE (SQL standard TIME WITH TIME ZONE) and OffsetDateTime is mapped to TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE (SQL standard TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE).

If the underlying is TIMESTAMP, then switching to use OffsetDateTime is not guaranteed to work, because JDBC does not define such a mapping. JDBC only defines a mapping to LocalDateTime, so a compliant driver may not (and possibly more strongly, should not, because interpretation/conversion will be ambiguous) support a mapping to OffsetDateTime.

Small addendum for my second comment, LocalDateTime is also defined for DATE and TIME, at least for setObject (see table B-5 in JDBC 4.3)
